# How to "fold" array values in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am a Postgresql newcomer and I'd like to know is it possible to calculate the following:

```
select T.result + 
    -- here I want to do the following:
    -- iterate through T.arr1 and T.arr2 items and add their values
    -- to the T.result using the rules:
    -- if arr1 item is 1 then add 10, if arr1 item is 2 or 3 then add 20,
    -- if arr2 item is 3 then add 15, if arr2 item is 4 then add 20, else add 30

from (
    select 5 as result, array[1,2,3] as arr1, array[3,4,5] as arr2
) as T
```

So that for these arrays the query will produce: 5+10+20+20+15+20+30 = 120.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the array lengths always 3?

Comment: it is kind of 'artifical' example just to demonstrate my problem. No, let's assume their lengths are not always 3.

Comment: Can you post the expected output from your sample data?

Comment: as I said, the query should give us "120".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE val 
           WHEN 1 THEN 10
           WHEN 2 THEN 20
           WHEN 3 THEN 20
           END)
FROM unnest(array[1,2,3]) as val
```

To get the sum of array.

The full query will look like:

```
select T.result + 
       (SELECT SUM(CASE val 
               WHEN 1 THEN 10
               WHEN 2 THEN 20
               WHEN 3 THEN 20
               END)
        FROM  unnest(arr1) as val) +
       (SELECT SUM(CASE val 
               WHEN 3 THEN 15
               WHEN 4 THEN 20
               ELSE 30
               END)
        FROM  unnest(arr2) as val)   
from (
    select 5 as result, array[1,2,3] as arr1, array[3,4,5] as arr2
) as T
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/563)